# ARM DS5 floating license issue: Vendor daemon is down

Tags: arm, ds-5

I am getting the error:

> armlmd: The desired vendor daemon is down.

I have tried all the methods by reinstalling everything and also downloaded again the license file I have received from ARM. armlmd is not starting. The error displayed is

```
(armlmd) No features to serve, exiting
(armlmd) EXITING DUE TO SIGNAL 27 Exit reason 4
```

It is asking if I am using the right license file. The same license file I have been using for a while now and it was working. Recently it has stopped though I have a validity until next year.

I have contacted the ARM team as well.

Comment: Why don't you use gcc? Licence issues are non-existent.

Comment: @halfer since it was a critical issue for me i posted the query here as well. I could finally find the solution and posted the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could get an update on this issue. Since the license was a 3 server license 2 servers need to be running at a time for the license to work. It is still strange that the license worked without 2 servers running at the same time initially. But to avoid any ambiguities, it is necessary 2 servers are running at the same time and best case is all 3 servers are running. After setting up 2 servers to run i could solve the issue.